# Report Builder that integrates with MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, reporting

I have to create something similar to [Report Builder and SSRS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239314.aspx) or [Open RPT](http://www.xtuple.com/openrpt) but for a MFC application.

The idea is to be able to create and edit a **template** for **reports** that have to be **printed** afterwards. I am not confined to using MFC (I am allowed to use C#, QT, etc..), but whatever I use, it has to integrate in a MFC document application and be able to do drag and drop/resize and edit of containers (for example tables, image containers, etc).

There are some options that I considered (but they all seem overkill):

- **XPS**, it allows for easy printing but it does not allow for editing/drag and drop.
- **DirectDraw**, but this seems like a lot of work and I do not know if/how the printing functionality can be implemented.
- **QGraphicsView** from QT, but I am afraid of the complications that can arise because of the integration part.

Are there any components that I can use? It does not have to be free (but that would be nice), but I should be able to integrate it in my application without installing additional software on the clients machine.

Note: I use MFC9 with Visual Studio 2010. And the target PCs have Windows 7 and Windows 8 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All major components vendors have this kind of control in a way or another, my personal choice is DevExpress, but you can also look at Telerik, Syncfusion and others, just be sure that the Report Designer component can be redistributed to your end users.

Comment: +1 for DevExpress, even if it might be a bit hard to integrate in MFC